# Reliable alternative to replication for continous data sync between two databases

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, replication

I have one central database and 25 client databases and all have same schema.

I want that whenever some changes are done in some tables of the central database then these changes flow down to the client database.

The databases  used is SQL Express so I cannot use replication.
The solution that I have today is to make keep track of the changes in the central database and then a program makes a text file with these changes and sends them down to the client databases.Another program reads these text files and updates the client database.

There are three problems with this:-
1. The files get lost or arrive in jumbled order which messes up the client data
2. the process is slow
3. the programs are sometimes shutdown so the whole sync flow gets stopped.

Is there a reliable alternative that is fast and secure ?
I wonder how banking software are made ...they never lose transactions and they are fast.

Answer (score 3):

Add an `UpdateDate` column to all the entities that need to be replicated. At each client add a `linked server` to the central repository. Now, every 5 minutes or so, poll your central repository for changes using the last `UpdateDate` of a client entity and grab the delta. 
Then use `merge` or `insert` and `update` to merge data on the client. That's a very reliable way of doing homebrew replication. To keep track of deleted elements you would either want to mark them as deleted or have another table to keep track of entity kind and its reference, again combined with `UpdateDate` for replication.

**Update**
Then you mention transactions and banking software. When you do your replication via files, we ain't talkin' about no transactional replication here, not by a long shot.

If you need transactional consistency you need to subscribe to the transaction flow of the data warehouse.

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to be unhelpful and you haven't given any background about your business needs, but you have to decide if your priority is really "fast and secure" or if it's actually "cheap". Replicating changes between multiple databases in a reliable, consistent way is not easy (as you know) and it's highly unlikely that you will be able to develop a solution yourself that has the features, stability and performance of SQL Server replication.

SQL Express can be a replication subscriber, by the way, so it's not clear why it doesn't meet your needs. But if it doesn't, you should estimate the cost to your business (or customer) of dealing with issues caused by an unreliable solution: your time, business downtime, finding and correcting incorrect data, customer complaints, lost business etc. Then compare that to the cost of 25 SQL Server licenses (you should certainly be able to get a good discount when you order that volume), additional hardware (if any) and the costs of training, consulting and/or learning how to use replication. Then extrapolate those costs over 5 years or so. You may find that it's cheaper just to buy the solution you need. And of course buying the full SQL Server edition means you get a lot of other new features that might be useful to you.

If you (or your boss) is really determined to get something for nothing, you might want to investigate PostgreSQL or MySQL. They both have free replication solutions that seem to be widely enough used to be reliable for many companies. Of course, you then need to calculate the costs of switching to a new database platform.

Comment: The problem is they dont want to pay 7000 USD for the sql license so we are looking for a cheaper solution. Secondly we want to sell the solution to smaller clients who have 1 central server and maybe 2 clients , so for them the high cost of SQL SERVER is a problem. If SQL Express can somehow act like a publisher then that would solve the issue for us

Comment: As I said, you can't look at a single price in isolation. 7000 dollars is nothing compared to the costs that I mentioned and as someone else said, it's a small amount of development time. Calculate how much of your time 7000 dollars buys, then ask yourself (and your boss!) if you can re-create replication and all the other SQL Server features that you might use (SSIS? Service Broker?) in that time. Again, I don't want to sound unsympathetic, but your boss needs to understand a) the relationship between time and money and b) the implications of using commercial software.

Comment: You also can't take the single price in isolation. $7,000 is nothing compared to the costs of provisioning a new server, and moving MSDTC settings, linked server settings, synonym settings, logins, and of course the databases, to the new server. Then there's the hour or 3 of downtime for the business. And then you discover that replication breaks the system when it adds triggers to your database that lead to a complicated chain of trigger recursion. The point being that replication has issues, and you can spend thousands of dollars trying to understand the system that isn't well understood.

Answer (score 0):

If you have one central database and 25 clients, you can easily do it with one (yes only one) SQL server licence for the main database. Subscribers to this database can run SQL express. As long as users access the the client databases, you are not even obliged to buy SQL CALs.

Back to banking software, be sure that they are paying good money for their server licenses! So don't be surprised if these are reliable and fast ...

Comment: Hello Phillipe , problem is they dont want to pay for an SQL license which is about 7000 USD

Comment: 7000 usd are more or less the cost of 15 days of development , which is a lot less than the cost of a reliable hand made solution ... and I thought it was cheaper than that. No 'bizness packs' sold with a server licence and some other stuff ?